# regex date without the zero

Tags: regex

I need to be able to allow dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY where the leading month and day can have a leading zero or not where appropriate

In other words: 
01-09 or 1-9 are acceptable months

01-09 or 1-9 are acceptable days

I am very close with this:

```
/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))\/\d{4}/
```

With my limited knowledge I thought doing this would allow for a leading zero (or not)

```
/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))\/\d{4}/
```

But that allows for dates such as 13/31/2008, for reasons I can't explain.

Question:
I need a regular expression that allows all possible dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY where the month or day can contain leading zeros (or not) where both will pass.

Edit:

I am working with a 3rd party system that fails downstream if a user’s input is not a real date. The only tool I have against the input is Regex check. (For those that down voted my question)

Comment: Why are you over complicating it?  `/(\d{1,2}\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/`, then do a separate check to make sure the day and month are ok (good luck with a regex that allows 2/29, but only on leap years)

Comment: I am inserting to another system that fails if it’s not a correct date (not worried about leap year). So 99/99/9999 won’t work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, all you need is to anchor the regex to start and end (and make the zero in months optional too), like this:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))\/\d{4}$
```

Now it won't accept 13/31/2008.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something simple. Much appreciated.